# Pandas: how do I use the columns as the indices and then have repeats in the former indices become repeats in the new indices?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Basically I'm trying to convert this,

```
dft = pd.DataFrame({1: [0.1,0.4,0.2,0.5],2:[0.4,0.5,0.3,0.4],3:[0.2,0.4,0.6,0.7]}, index=['t1', 't1','t2','t2'])
dft.index.name = "tt"
dft.columns.name='num'

num 1   2   3
tt          
t1  0.1 0.4 0.2
t1  0.4 0.5 0.4
t2  0.2 0.3 0.6
t2  0.5 0.4 0.7
```

into this,

```
tt  t1  t2
num     
1   0.1 0.2
1   0.4 0.5
2   0.4 0.3
2   0.5 0.4
3   0.2 0.6
3   0.4 0.7
```

using (probably) pandas methods.
I can include the code on how the second df was created, if that helps. I figure there may be an answer on this already, but other things come up in search attempts I've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
(dft.set_index(dft.groupby('tt').cumcount(), append=True) # enumerate the rows within each `tt`
    .unstack(level=-1).T                                  # pivot the enumeration and flip
    .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)                      # remove enumeration     
)
```

Output:

```
tt    t1   t2
num          
1    0.1  0.2
1    0.4  0.5
2    0.4  0.3
2    0.5  0.4
3    0.2  0.6
3    0.4  0.7
```

Comment: You were faster, I had the same ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you could do:

1. group DataFrame by 'tt'
2. aggregate items into list
3. transpose DataFrame
4. Use explode by 't1' and 't2' column

```py
dft = pd.DataFrame({1: [0.1,0.4,0.2,0.5],2:[0.4,0.5,0.3,0.4],3:[0.2,0.4,0.6,0.7]}, index=['t1', 't1','t2','t2'])
dft.index.name = "tt"
dft.columns.name='num'

new_dft = (
    dft.groupby('tt')
    .agg(lambda x: list(x))
    .transpose()
    .explode(['t1', 't2'])
)

new_dft
```

```
tt  t1  t2
num     
1   0.1 0.2
1   0.4 0.5
2   0.4 0.3
2   0.5 0.4
3   0.2 0.6
3   0.4 0.7
```

Comment: Cool but good to avoid hardcoding with `dft.index.unique().tolist()` for `['t1', 't2']` to be more generalizable.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
(pd.concat([
    x.droplevel(level=0) for _, x in dft.stack().groupby(level=0)], axis=1)
 .sort_index().set_axis(dft.index.unique(), axis=1))
```

Output:

```
tt    t1   t2
num          
1    0.1  0.2
1    0.4  0.5
2    0.4  0.3
2    0.5  0.4
3    0.2  0.6
3    0.4  0.7
```